# Project Euler #2 (Even Fibonacci numbers) in Swift

Tags: programming-challenge, fibonacci-sequence, swift

I figured working through Project Euler problems in Swift would be a good way to learn any tips or tricks.  For example, tuples are something I'm not used to using, but they proved useful here.  Using things makes me more confident with them, so perhaps this will help me find other uses for them in the future.

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the
>   previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will
>   be:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
>
> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not
>   exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

Here is my solution:

```
func swap(inout left: Any, inout right: Any) {
    let swap = left
    right = left
    left = swap
}

func findNextEvenFibonacci(var firstFibonacci: Int = 0, var secondFibonacci: Int = 1) -> (Int, Int) {
    do {
        firstFibonacci += secondFibonacci
        swap(&firstFibonacci, &secondFibonacci)
    } while firstFibonacci % 2 != 0

    return (firstFibonacci, secondFibonacci)
}

let maxFibonacci: Int = 4_000_000
var fibonacci: (first: Int, next: Int) = (0,1)
var sumOfEvenFibonnaccis: Int = 0

while fibonacci.next < maxFibonacci {
    fibonacci = findNextEvenFibonacci(firstFibonacci: fibonacci.first, secondFibonacci: fibonacci.next)
    sumOfEvenFibonnaccis += fibonacci.first
}

let answer = sumOfEvenFibonnaccis
```

Comment: Isn't `swap` already built in? Quoting from [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html): "[...] you can use Swift’s existing `swap` function rather than providing your own implementation."

Comment: Welp, apparently so.  I just commented my `swap` function out and it still works just fine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following is similar to Flambino's approach, but creates a Swift
`SequenceType` so that you can use the Swift library functions
`filter()` and `reduce()` to iterate over
the elements:

```
struct FibonacciSequence : SequenceType {
    let upperBound : Int

    func generate() -> GeneratorOf<Int> {
        var current = 1
        var next = 1
        return GeneratorOf<Int>() {
            if current > self.upperBound {
                return nil
            }
            let result = current
            current = next
            next += result
            return result
        };
    }
}

let fibseq = lazy(FibonacciSequence(upperBound: 4_000_000))
let sum = reduce(fibseq.filter { $0 % 2 == 0 }, 0) { $0 + $1 }
```

See [here](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/swift-sequences) for more information about sequences and generators. 
[This nice application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25153544/1187415) made me actually understand how you can create your own sequences.

`lazy()` creates a `LazySequence`, whose `filter()` method returns the elements "on demand", e.g. as needed in the summation. The 
`filter()` function would return an *array* of all even Fibonacci numbers
before starting the summation. (Kudos to @jtbandes for his suggestion).

---

*Update:* Due to major changes in the Swift programming language,
the above code does not compile anymore with the current Swift 2.1/Xcode 7. Here is an updated version fore anybody's convenience:

```
struct FibonacciSequence : SequenceType {
    let upperBound : Int

    func generate() -> AnyGenerator<Int> {
        var current = 1
        var next = 1
        return anyGenerator {
            if current > self.upperBound {
                return nil
            }
            let result = current
            current = next
            next += result
            return result
        };
    }
}

let fibseq = FibonacciSequence(upperBound: 4_000_000).lazy
let sum = fibseq.filter { $0 % 2 == 0 }.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }
```

Comment: Very nice. I reckoned there'd be a built-in "generator"  type of some sort but I didn't know of it (and I failed to find it when I [quickly] looked, it seems)

Comment: @MartinR Feel free to come join the regulars in [the 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) sometime!

Comment: I really like this answer because generating sequences seems it will be very useful for the rest of the Project Euler problems plus outside of Project Euler--but for this specific question, won't this be quite slow comparatively?  We generate all the Fibonacci numbers, then we filter down to the evens, then we add the evens up, rather than just adding as we go.

Comment: Have you tried `lazy()`? There should be a version of `filter` which is lazy too.

Comment: @jtbandes: Great suggestion! It had tried it before and could not figure it out, but I think that I got it know to work. I have updated the answer accordingly. Thanks again!

Comment: @MartinR Cool! I am working on a more general lazy solution which I'll post in a few minutes if I get it working.

Answer (score 12):

I can only suggest a faster* math-based algorithm:

The fibonacci numbers are: 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34 and etc.

The even ones are: 0 at index 0, 2 at index 3, 8 at index 6, 34 at index 9 and so on.

This suggests that every third fibonacci number is even (starting from 0). Let's try and prove this by induction:

**WARNING MATH AHEAD**

We have already proved a few base cases: index 0 and 3 are even fibonacci numbers.

Suppose `Fibonacci(3 * n)` is even.

```
Fibonacci(3 * (n + 1)) = Fibonacci(3n + 3)
                       = Fibonacci(3n + 2) + Fibonacci(3n + 1)
                       = 2 * Fibonacci(3n + 1) + Fibonacci(3n)
```

Since `2 * Fibonacci(3n + 1)` is even, and by the induction hypothesis, `Fibonacci(3n)` is even, which means the sum is even as well, and so `Fibonacci(3 * (n+1))` must also be even. Thus induction is complete and we have proved that every third Fibonacci number is even.

Next we have to prove that all the other numbers are not even. Since we know `Fibonacci(1) = 1` is odd, then using the same logic as previously, we can show that `Fibonacci(3n + 1) = 2 * Fibonacci(3n - 1) + Fibonacci(3n + 1)` which is guaranteed to be odd. Similarly the result will be obtained for all `n = 2 mod 3`.

**END OF MATH**

This simplifies your task to just summing every third fibonacci number, with no need to check if it is even or not, as we have just proved they are the only even fibonacci numbers.

- (DISCLAIMER) In the Python scripts I wrote to test this, the difference in time wasn't obvious until roughly 10<sup>1000</sup>

Comment: To be clear, this just eliminates checking whether or not the result is even, right?

Comment: Interesting. I suspected there was a pattern to the parity, but... math is _hard_ (and I was lazy) :P

Comment: @nhgrif That's my understanding, although [there are ways of generating the _Nth_ number](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Swift) in the sequence that look interesting on their own. Of course, if you use an algorithm that still produces the entire sequence, uh, sequentially to find the _Nth_ number, just checking parity along the way is no doubt simpler

Comment: @nhgrif That is indeed correct. It saves on a few modulos. That is all.

Comment: Your statement about even Fibonacci numbers can also be deduced from the formula \$ \gcd(F_m, F_n) = F_{\gcd(m, n)} \$: \$ \gcd(F_m, 2) = \gcd(F_m, F_3) = F_{\gcd(m, 3)} \$ which is \$ F_3 = 2 \$ or \$ F_1 = 1 \$, depending on whether \$ m \$ is a multiple of 3 or not.

Comment: That is a very interesting formula, and quite clever too, but its proof is no simpler than this one. It is more general though, which is nice. Here is a proof on math.stackexchange for anyone that's interested: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/60353/162023

Comment: @Flambino after solving a PE problem with a registered account, one gets acces to a pdf with the math behind it (if it exists at all). It will go through the derivation of an optimal solution.

Answer (score 8):

*Disclaimer: This is the most I've ever written in Swift. In other words, I barely know what I'm doing.*

My gut feeling, Swift or no Swift, is the the `findNextEvenFibonacci` function is a little too specific on its own. I'd probably have another function that just generates the next Fibonacci number - even or odd. Its parity is then checked when summing up.

Also, I don't know how to feel about the tuple. While it's a simple, direct solution a tuple also feels a little opaque. Given that structs are quite powerful in Swift, a fully declared struct with some functions might be better.

Here's my naïve attempt:

```
struct FibonacciPair {
    var current: Int
    var previous: Int

    // using the name successor, since that's what Int
    // calls its next-in-sequence function
    func successor() -> FibonacciPair {
        return FibonacciPair(current: current + previous, previous: current)
    }
}

var generator = FibonacciPair(current: 1, previous: 1)
var sum = 0

while generator.current < 4_000_000 {
    if generator.current % 2 == 0 {
        sum += generator.current
    }
    generator = generator.successor()
}

let answer = sum
```

This is of course the sort of task that can be accomplished in a hundred different ways - the above is just what came to my mind first.

*Aside: A few of those hundred other ways would be wholly procedurally without any functions or structs or other such contraptions - just a `while` loop and some variables. But I figure the idea here is also to play around with Swift.*

Perhaps it'd be reasonable to extend `Int` with an `isEven` function, while we're at it. It's basic enough to be of general use as a core type extension, and it'd clean up the `while` loop above a little bit

```
extension Int {
    func isEven() -> Bool {
        return self % 2 == 0
    }
}
```

An alternative approach might be a Fibonacci-number generator that takes a closure. If only a closure could `break` the loop in which it's called instead of returning a bool... oh, well

```
func eachFibonacciNumber(iterator: (Int) -> (Bool)) {
    var current = 1
    var previous = 0

    while iterator(current + previous) {
        swap(&previous, &current)
        current += previous
    }
}

var sum = 0

eachFibonacciNumber() {
    // note: I definitely should be checking $0 < limit *before*
    // incrementing the sum... but it looks prettier if I don't :P
    if $0.isEven() { sum += $0 }
    return $0 < 4_000_000
}

let answer = sum
```

`eachFibonacciNumber` is a terrible Ruby'esque-but-not-really name, but you get the idea.

The limit could also just be an argument of course, which would avoid the bool return:

```
func fibonacciNumbersUpTo(limit: UInt, iterator: (Int) -> ()) {
    var current = 1
    var previous = 0

    while current < limit {
        iterator(current)
        swap(&previous, &current)
        current += previous
    }
}

var sum = 0
fibonacciNumbersUpTo(4_000_000) {
  if $0.isEven() { sum += $0 }
}
```

That's is probably the nicest, most straightforward of the bunch, in my opinion.

In either case, though, the idea is to have a way to get the regular Fibonacci sequence, and then deciding what to do with each number, rather than using a specific "only even Fibonacci numbers" device. Of course, either of the above could be form the basis for such a device.

In any case, going through Project Euler with Swift is a nice idea - I'll probably do the same :)

Comment: Regarding your disclaimer: I think that can be said for most Swift developers.

Comment: @syb0rg Heh, yeah, I guess so. But considering I was quick to install the Xcode beta, but haven't gotten around to actually _using_ it, I'm a little embarrassed nonetheless :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is an approach using a general `RecurrenceRelation` struct which can be used to write any recurrence, not just the Fibonacci sequence (the Fibonacci sequence is defined by initial conditions (1,1) and the relation `T[n] = T[n-1] + T[n-2]`). I also define `takeWhile` as an extension to `LazySequence` so the functionality doesn't have to be built into `RecurrenceRelation` — Swift has a built-in `prefix` but it seems to be designed for random-access collections only.

```
struct RecurrenceRelation<E> : SequenceType {
    let initialCondition: [E]
    let relation: (T: [E], n: Int) -> E

    init(_ initialCondition: [E], relation: (T: [E], n: Int) -> E) {
        self.initialCondition = initialCondition
        self.relation = relation
    }

    func generate() -> GeneratorOf<E> {
        var memory = initialCondition
        var i = 0

        return GeneratorOf<E> {
            if i < memory.count { return memory[i++] }
            memory.append(self.relation(T: memory, n: memory.count))
            memory.removeAtIndex(0)
            return memory.last
        }
    }
}

extension LazySequence {
    func takeWhile(pred: S.Generator.Element -> Bool) -> LazySequence<SequenceOf<S.Generator.Element>> {
        return lazy(SequenceOf { () -> GeneratorOf<S.Generator.Element> in
            var g = self.generate()
            return GeneratorOf<S.Generator.Element> {
                let n = g.next()
                if n == nil || !pred(n!) { return nil }
                return n
            }
        })
    }
}

let fib = RecurrenceRelation([1, 1]) { (T, n) in T[n-1] + T[n-2] }

let n = reduce(lazy(fib).takeWhile { $0 < 4_000_000 }.filter { $0 % 2 == 0 }, 0, +)
```