# Prime Factorization

Tags: c, objective-c, primes

I'm doing an Objective-C project and I need to do some prime factorization and so I came up with the following algorithm which is 99% C, except for the array part which was easiest to implement in Objective-C because it dynamically allocates new memory for the elements as they are simply added. The Objective-C part is pretty self-explanatory.

I'm mainly looking for feedback on the algorithm, not necessarily the coding style and such, but I will gladly feedback on something I can improve on!  On my machine with O3 optimizations, I get just under two seconds on factorizing 1234567890. I really don't know if that is good or bad. One thing I would like to add to it is a table for previously calculated factorizations, when on large numbers you will most likely encounter  numbers more than once (e.g. 4, 6, etc.). I could maybe add to the function that if it's even, add a 2 to the factors and don't do the division/prime check which may improve performance.

```
//Declare an array
NSMutableArray *factors;

bool isPrime(long n) {

    //Check if even or ends in a five
    if ((n % 2 == 0 && n > 2) || (n > 5 && n % 10 == 5)) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (n == 2) return 1;

    //set upper bound to square root
    long u = sqrt(n);
    long c = 0;

    for (long i = 3; i <= u; i+=2)
        if (n % i == 0) {
            c++;
            break;
        }

    return !c;
}


void factorize(long n) {

    //If prime return
    if (isPrime(n)) {
        [factors addObject:@(n)];
        return;
    }

    for (long i = n/2; i > 1; i--) {
        if (n % i) continue; //Check if indivisible

        long d = n/i;

        bool iP = isPrime(i), dP = isPrime(d);

        if (iP)
            [factors addObject:@(i)];
        else
            factorize(i);

        if (dP)
            [factors addObject:@(d)];
        else
            factorize(d);

        return;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    factors = [NSMutableArray array];

    long n = 1234567890;
    factorize(n);

    NSLog(@"%@", factors);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why bother optimizing a slow algorithm when you can just replace it with another (easy to implement) algorithm that will instantly factor all 64-bit integers in under few thousand or so simple iterations? Work smart, not hard - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm

Comment: @awashburn This is prime factorization, not primality testing..

Comment: @Thomas I'd still argue against a stochastic algorithm...

Comment: @awashburn The algorithm I linked is deterministic, and randomizing it doesn't really gain anything. Most nontrivial factorization algorithms are probabilistic though, that's just the reality of things, for 64 bit inputs though I find deterministic Miller-Rabin and rho (after trial division by the first few primes for efficiency) is as fast as it gets. Although I haven't tried ECM, but I suspect it has too much overhead in this case.

Comment: @Thomas But the function you linked to uses stochastic principals to define a partial (non-total) function. Your right it is deterministic, still wouldn't recommend a partial function...

Comment: @awashburn I see your point, heuristically it works very well but it is based on statistics ideas. I would still take it any day over trial division though, because it simply *is faster*, especially since it isn't hard to implement (and, to be frank, way easier than some of the convoluted 'optimized' trial division implementations I've seen).

Comment: @Thomas We'll just have to wait a few decades until Number Theory matures and develops a better algorithm...

Comment: @awashburn There are better algorithms, they are just more complicated. The one I linked has extremely good performance/implementation cost ratio. Using trial division alone to factor integers over 16 bits or so is like using bubble sort to sort a large array. It doesn't make any sense. I will stop here though because the system is complaining about the long comment chain.

Answer (score 17):

Your algorithm tries to find the *largest* factors first.
This is ineffective because you have to test each possible factor whether it is a
prime number or not.

It is much more effective to start with the *smallest* factor.
If you divide the number by each factor found this way then you will get *only* prime factors, and the prime testing
function `isPrime()` becomes obsolete. You start with dividing by 2 and then test possible odd
factors in increasing order. (If you have a pre-computed list of primes then this can be further improved.)

On my computer this reduced the runtime for the factorization of 1234567890
from 1.6 to 0.00005 seconds.

In addition, a global `factors` variable is no longer necessary with this change,
and your method could look like this:

```
NSMutableArray * primeFactorization(long n) {

    NSMutableArray *factors = [NSMutableArray array];

    // Divide by 2:
    while (n > 1 && n % 2 == 0) {
        [factors addObject:@(2)];
        n /= 2;
    }

    // Divide by 3, 5, 7, ...
    //
    // i is a possible *smallest* factor of the (remaining) number n.
    // If i * i > n then n is either 1 or a prime number.
    for (long i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2) {
        while (n > 1 && n % i == 0) {
            [factors addObject:@(i)];
            n /= i;
        }
    }

    if (n > 1) {
        // Append last prime factor:
        [factors addObject:@(n)];
    }

    return factors;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    long n = 1234567890;

    NSDate *startTime = [NSDate date];
    NSArray *factors = primeFactorization(n);
    NSLog(@"time: %f", -[startTime timeIntervalSinceNow]);

    NSLog(@"%@", factors);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since you don't use `argc` & `argv`, I would put `void` in their spot.  At least, that is what I would do in C.  Other than that, very good advice: +1

Answer (score 8):

Feedback on the algorithm

```
//Check if even or ends in a five
if ((n % 2 == 0 && n > 2) || (n > 5 && n % 10 == 5)) {
    return 0;
}
```

The part which checks if your number is divided by 5 makes very little optimization, since it's checked on the second iteration of the loop which follow.

```
for (long i = 3; i <= u; i+=2)
    if (n % i == 0) {
        c++;
        break;
    }
```

I suggest creating a cache of all prime numbers up to, say, 100000, and rewrite the loop like this:

```
for (long i = 0; i < primeCacheSize; i++)
    if (n % primeCache[i] == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
for (long i = 100001; i <= u; i++)
    if (n % i == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
return 0;
```

This is a bit strange:

```
//If prime return
if (isPrime(n)) {
    [factors addObject:@(n)];
    return;
}

for (long i = n/2; i > 1; i--) {
    if (n % i) continue; //Check if indivisible
```

How will this code work on 208907 * 208907 * 208907 (9117147423118643)? Your function `isPrime` will determine that n is divided by 208907, return false, and you'll start iterating from `9117147423118643 / 2` downwards. Looks like an infinite (and useless) loop.

The solution I may suggest: 
make your `isPrime` function return the number itself if n is prime or number's divider if it isn't.

```
for (long i = 0; i < primeCacheSize; i++)
    if (n % primeCache[i] == 0) {
        return primeCache[i];
    }
for (long i = 100001; i <= u; i++)
    if (n % i == 0) {
        return i;
    }
return n;
```

And rewrite factorize like that:

```
void factorize(long n) {

//If prime return
while (n > 1) {
    divider = isPrime(n);
    [factors addObject:@(divider)];
    n /= divider;
}
```

Comment: I'd limit the prime cache loops with `u` as well to avoid unnecessary checks: `i < primeCacheSize && i <= u`.

Comment: Also, with the suggestion of having `isPrime` return the divider: the function name `isPrime` is now misleading as I'd expect a boolean value to be returned, so its name should be changed to something like `firstPrimeOf` or whatever. Also, I'd recommend using a `NSMutableSet` instead of an `NSMutableArray` for `factors`.

Comment: A note on your prime cache. if you have `10000` primes cached, and the number is not in the cache and the number is greater then the upper limit of the cache, you should not start the next loop'

Comment: If the number is not in the cache, you should start the second loop *not* at `i=cacheSize+1` but at `i=cache[cacheSize]+2` (`+2` so it's an odd number), and the loop should increment by `i+=2`. This ensures that you are only checking odd numbers.

Answer (score 8):

Given that this answer is marked with the [c](/questions/tagged/c) tag, and the user quite appropriately points out that the code is 99% [c](/questions/tagged/c), I decided that it might be worthwhile to demonstrate how simple the C solution to this problem is.

There are only two aspects of Objective-C the user uses.

1. `NSMutableArray`.  This is convenient and it handles the resizing of the array for us.  However, it's important to note that there's nothing magical about how an `NSMutableArray` resizes.  Objective-C mutable arrays are resized in the same way as a C-array.
2. `NSNumber`.  We don't actually see `NSNumber` anywhere directly, but that's what the `@()` syntax is doing--creating `NSNumber` objects.  And why?  Because `NSArray` can not store primitive data types.  It must store pointers.

Unless the actual intent is to use this array in some other Objective-C code where the `NSNumber` objects will actually be easier to deal with, there's not a particularly good reason to use Objective-C here, except perhaps being uncomfortable in working with C-style arrays.

So, here's my solution to this problem in C.

As a starting point, I used [*Martin R's answer*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/62029/36366), which actually also is very similar to the algorithm I used for [a slightly different problem here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60889/project-euler-3-largest-prime-factor-in-swift).

*Please note, the following code snippet includes the code from Martin's answer so that the two solutions can be compared side-by-side in case he ever edits/removes his answer.*

Martin's very good answer:

```
NSMutableArray * primeFactorization(long n) {

    NSMutableArray *factors = [NSMutableArray array];

    // Divide by 2:
    while (n > 1 && n % 2 == 0) {
        [factors addObject:@(2)];
        n /= 2;
    }

    // Divide by 3, 5, 7, ...
    //
    // i is a possible *smallest* factor of the (remaining) number n.
    // If i * i > n then n is either 1 or a prime number.
    for (long i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2) {
        while (n > 1 && n % i == 0) {
            [factors addObject:@(i)];
            n /= i;
        }
    }

    if (n > 1) {
        // Append last prime factor:
        [factors addObject:@(n)];
    }

    return factors;
}
```

My approach in straight C:

```
long * cPrimeFactorization(long n, long *factorCount) {
    long currentSize = 2;
    long currentIndex = 0;
    long *factors = malloc(sizeof(long) * currentSize);

    while (n > 1 && n % 2 == 0) {
        factors[currentIndex++] = 2;
        if (currentIndex >= currentSize) {
            currentSize *= 2;
            long *reallocFactors = realloc(factors, currentSize * sizeof(long));
            if (reallocFactors) {
                factors = reallocFactors;
            } else {
                printf("realloc failed");
                free(factors);
                return NULL;
            }
        }
        n /= 2;
    }

    for (long i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2) {
        while (n > 1 && n % i == 0) {
            factors[currentIndex++] = i;
            if (currentIndex >= currentSize) {
                currentSize *= 2;
                long *reallocFactors = realloc(factors, currentSize * sizeof(long));
                if (reallocFactors) {
                    factors = reallocFactors;
                } else {
                    printf("realloc failed");
                    free(factors);
                    return NULL;
                }
            }
            n /= i;
        }
    }

    if (n > 1) {
        factors[currentIndex++] = n;
    }
    *factorCount = currentIndex; 
    return factors;
}
```

Running them side by side:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    long n = 1234567890;

    NSDate *startTime = [NSDate date];
    NSArray *oFactors = primeFactorization(n);
    NSLog(@"time (Objective-C): %f", -[startTime timeIntervalSinceNow]);

    startTime = [NSDate date];
    long factorCount;
    long * cFactors = cPrimeFactorization(n, &factorCount);
    NSLog(@"time (C): %f", -[startTime timeIntervalSinceNow]);

    NSLog(@"%@", oFactors);
    for (long i = 0; i < factorCount; ++i) {
        printf("%li\n", cFactors[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For the sake of benchmarking consistency, I just used the Objective-C approach (because Martin already had it and I didn't feel like looking up a C approach).  I tried a handful of different numbers and ran them all multiple times.  The C approach runs faster in every case.

More than speed, the C approach actually takes less total memory than the Objective-C approach.  Not only does the Objective-C array have more overhead than the C array, (each index is the same size, 8-bytes), but the Objective-C array is an index of pointers to objects.  So the Objective-C array is already slightly bigger than the C array, plus there's several magnitudes more memory space for holding all of the `NSNumber` objects out on the heap as well.

And that we have to spend so much time creating these `NSNumber` objects out on the stack is part of the reason the Objective-C solution is slower.  It's also slower because passing messages to objects (the `addObject:` we call several times) is very slow compared to being able to directly insert a value in at a memory location (which is what we do with the C-array).

*Please note, I'm definitely an Objective-C programmer, and I am not a C programmer in the slightest.  My C code almost certainly has room for improvement I'd imagine... but as Objective-C programmers, we must always keep in mind that pure-C should always be an option.*

---

*As a note, this speed (and memory) difference becomes particularly noticeable with very large powers of two.  For example, with 2^49th, which is 562,949,953,421,312, the Objective-C solution takes almost 3 times as long on my computer.*

Comment: With regards to `printf("realloc failed");`, the caller should handle reporting errors.

Comment: Yeah, probably.  I'm not familiar with C-standards or what should be done in a case like this... I just know it's possible for `realloc` to fail...

Comment: @nhgrif: My last comment was wrong and I have deleted it. But it would be interesting if - after you added the necessary allocation to the `while (n > 1 && n % 2 == 0)` loop - the difference is still particularly noticeable for powers of two.

Answer (score 1):

There are math potential problems with `double sqrt(double)`

```
bool isPrime(long n) {
  ...
  long u = sqrt(n);
  ...
  for (long i = 3; i <= u; i+=2)
```

1. Conversion from `long` to `double` may lose precision.  Although `double` typically can represent every value of an `int54_t`, `long` could be wider such as 64 bits.
2. A *good* `sqrt()` will return the exact value for a perfect square, but not all `sqrt()` behave so nicely.  Code should be prepared for something like `sqrt(121)` --> `10.99999...`.
3. Since the `for()` loop has no trouble iterating a little pass ideal, recommend a simple solution for both above issues: Increase the upper limit by 1.

   ```
      long u = sqrt(n);
      u++;
   ```